# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping Default Values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

When mapping my Property with Fluent NHibernate, on insert, I would like to use the database default value only when my Property is null.  So for instance, if the db default is 100, and my property is null, it should insert 100, otherwise insert the value of my property ( say 25 ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by mapping override:

```
public class MyEntityMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<MyEntity>
{
     public void Override(AutoMapping<MyEntity> mapping)
     {
         mapping.Map(x => x.MyProperty).Default("100");
     }
}
```